# VBA Comma Separated Look-Up

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I'm looking to either use a formula or VBA to lookup values in column J associated with the same ID number and put them into any starting with "Master" in Column A separated by commas.

In the example below, I would like cell J2 to return 
"D, G, R, N" and if there ere any duplicates to only have them listed once. The values in column J are currently looking up values from another list using the formula :

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$J:$J,0)),"N", 
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$K:$K,0)),"D", 
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$L:$L,0)),"R", 
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$M:$M,0)),"G", 
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$N:$N,0)),"F",""))))), "")
```

[image: Master Image]

Comment: Would another way to state your problem be - For each ID, you want to return all the unique `Area` values that exist for it?

Comment: Yes, but only for the "Master" IDs, not for the ones that start with numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this UDF.  Since you're looking for a *formula*, put this in the blank cells in Column J.

```
=get_areas(C2)
```

Then add this in to a Workbook Module:

```
Function get_areas(ID As String) As String
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:A" & Cells(rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row)

Dim areas As String
For Each cel In rng
    If IsNumeric(Left(cel, 1)) And cel.Offset(0, 2) = ID Then
        If InStr(1, areas, cel.Offset(0, 9)) = 0 Then
            areas = cel.Offset(0, 9) & ", " & areas
        End If
    End If
Next cel

areas = Trim(Left(areas, Len(areas) - 2))
get_areas = areas
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I'm noticing that some of the ones that have duplicate values will show up in column J as "X," for example instead of just "X" - is there any way to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: @VictoriaG - Can you edit your OP with more examples? I changed the areas to `X / X / Z` for `789`, and get `Z, X`.  I can't reproduce the `X,`

Comment: apologies, it actually is not when it is a duplicate but rather when there is only one value. In your example above, it would occur if J8 was X and J9 and J10 were blank, then it would show X, in J7.

Comment: @VictoriaG - Hm, I can't seem to replicate the issue.  Do the empty cells have spaces in them, or are they indeed empty?

Comment: They are empty, except for the formula I was using to populate them (seen above). I am trying to use VBA to enter the get_areas function into the blank cells, but it doesn't seem to be working that way. Might you have any insight? Sub emptycells() Range("J2:J" & Cells.SpecialCells(11).row).Offset(1, -1).SpecialCells(4).Value = "=get_areas($C2)" End Sub

Comment: @VictoriaG - That sounds like a new question :)

Comment: It seems like the issue might be with this part of the function when I attempt to use it in VBA areas = Trim(Left(areas, Len(areas) - 2)). I started a new thread here. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53873304/enter-user-defined-function-into-column-using-vba

Comment: is there a way to make this a sub instead of a function? And have it only go into cells in column J that start with "Master" in column A? :)